# How does the Freepascal Memory Manager work on enlarging arrays

Tags: memory-management, freepascal

I recently stumbled over an issue within a FreePascal project I'm developing: The application requires a look-up array which may become very large during the runtime (a few million entries). Each array element is about 8 bytes in size.

I observed the following behavior of my application: If the array is already quite large (~130 MB), another enlargement will result in a peak in memory consumption and maybe also in a volatile raise of used RAM.

As far as I read, the peak may be explained with the internal behavior of the SetLength()-method which allocates memory with the size of the new array and then copies the old array to its new destination in memory.

But during examination of the sudden increase of used memory it seemed that there were situations where the "old" memory was not freed, resulting in a doubled usage of the RAM.

I was able to reproduce this behavior more clearly as I raised the steps in which the array was enlarged.

To become rid of this problem, I changed the memory manager to CMem and the issue was gone.

Unfortunately I did not found a clear description of the Free Pascal memory manager and I can only guess, that the space of the "old" (small) array is not used because the built-in memory manager wants the heap to be not-fragmented all the time, but I could not prove that.

Does someone of you have a source which describes the basic functionality of the Free Pascal memory manager and the C memory manager and/or the differences between both?

Thank you very much, kind regards

Alex

Comment: Check [http://svn.freepascal.org/svn/fpc/trunk/rtl/inc/dynarr.inc](http://svn.freepascal.org/svn/fpc/trunk/rtl/inc/dynarr.inc) function `fpc_dynarray_setlength` and [http://svn.freepascal.org/svn/fpc/trunk/rtl/inc/cmem.pp](http://svn.freepascal.org/svn/fpc/trunk/rtl/inc/cmem.pp)

Comment: Thank you very much! This describes how the SetLength() function works (and it indeed copies the whole array on enlarging), but does not provide any information about the memory management done "behind" GetMem ... As far as I can see the cmem.pp is only a header file for the libraries which are used to get the real memory acquisition done. Nevertheless thank you very much for your comment!

Comment: So why don't you simply trace through the memory allocation with the debugger?

Comment: If I had the source for the CMem and the FreePascal internal memory manager I could look it up even without debugger. At least I could not find any source for one of them ...

Comment: Every lazarus installation comes with source, and there are source archives for all releases on freepascal.org in various formats.

Comment: But unfortunately not with source of the Cmem since this is not implemented but used with a DLL... So a comparison of source is not possible here